# Print all possible paths in binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm trying to print all possible paths in a binary tree. I am able to print all root to leaf paths, but cannot figure out how to add leaf-to-leaf paths.(i'm using preorder traversal for root to leaf).
So, basically:

If my tree is

```
       6
     /    \
    4      0
   / \      \
  1   3      1
```

If  want to the code to print all the paths:

```
6,4,1
6,4,3
6,0,1
1,4,6,0,1
3,4,6,0,1 
1,4,3  
4,6,0  
4,6,0,1  
etc.
```

Can anyone please help me with this binary tree?
I would really appreciate your help, as I'm new to this society and to Python/Java.

Thanks

Comment: Finally: would `4,6,0` be valid?  That is, are you looking for all root-->leaf paths + all leaf--> leaf paths, or are you looking for every possible path from any node to any other node?

Comment: Haven't thought of that one. I will need actually all paths. So, 4, 6, 0 should also be in the list of paths.

Comment: Please place the additional information that you put in comments into your question. It seems that you want a path for any pair of nodes in the tree, so since your example tree has `6` nodes you want `6*5//2 == 15` paths. Is that correct? Also show us the data structure that you use for the binary tree--that would affect any answer.

Comment: Thanks for noting. I have edited the question a bit. I need all possible paths.

Comment: Then you want to find all the pathes in a DAG, and not in a tree. Think on a DAG.

Comment: why DAG? it is a binary tree and i want to find all the paths in the binary tree( root to leaf, leaf to leaf, etc.)

Comment: how large is the problem size?
For such little trees as shown you can simply brute force it: there are 5 edges, therefore there are 2^5=32 combinations to add/remove an edge.
Now for each edge combination check for two constraints: (a) the edges must form a single connected path, (b) at most 2 edges connected per vertex

Comment: this is just an example, but i would like to be able to generalize it to a bigger problem.

Answer (score 4):

One notable property of trees is that for every combination of node `(x, y)`, there exist a unique non-repeating path from `x` to `y`. In particular, this path can be found by finding the first common ancestor `z` of `x` and `y` and by taking the path `x -> z + z -> y`.

Thus an algorithm to find all path could look like this

```
for each pair of distinct nodes x, y in the tree:
    find all common ancestors of x and y
    let z be the lowest common acestor in the tree
    let p be the path from x to z
    append the path from z to y to p, excluding the duplicate z
    print p
```

Here is an object-oriented approach that implements the needed method to accomplish the above.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = None

        if left is not None:
            left.parent = self

        if right is not None:
            right.parent = self

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return a left-to-right iterator on the tree"""
        if self.left:
            yield from iter(self.left)
        yield self
        if self.right:
            yield from iter(self.right)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def get_ancestors(self):
        """Return a list of all ancestors including itself"""
        ancestors = {self}
        parent = self.parent
        while parent:
            ancestors.add(parent)
            parent = parent.parent

        return ancestors

    def get_path_to_ancestor(self, ancestor):
        """
        Return the path from self to ancestor as a list
        output format: [self, ..., ancestor]
        """
        path = []
        parent = self
        try:
            while True:
                path.append(parent)
                if parent is ancestor:
                    break
                else:
                    parent = parent.parent
        except AttributeError:
            return None

        return path

    def get_path_to(self, other):
        """
        Return the path from self to other as a list
        output format: [self, ..., first common acestor, ..., other]
        """
        common_ancestors = self.get_ancestors() & other.get_ancestors()
        first_common_ancestor = {
            a for a in common_ancestors
            if a.left not in common_ancestors and a.right not in common_ancestors
        }.pop()

        return self.get_path_to_ancestor(first_common_ancestor)\
               + list(reversed(other.get_path_to_ancestor(first_common_ancestor)))[1:]
```

Here is how it applies to the tree you provided as example.

```
tree = Tree(
    6,
    Tree(4,
         Tree(1),
         Tree(3)),
    Tree(0,
         Tree(1)))

nodes = list(tree)

for i in range(len(nodes)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(nodes)):
        print([t for t in nodes[i].get_path_to(nodes[j])])
```

Here are all paths that get printed.

```
[1, 4]
[1, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 4, 6, 0, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 0]
[4, 3]
[4, 6]
[4, 6, 0, 1]
[4, 6, 0]
[3, 4, 6]
[3, 4, 6, 0, 1]
[3, 4, 6, 0]
[6, 0, 1]
[6, 0]
[1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated. I will check it out now.

Comment: @user9436638 I updated the solution. The bottom code snippet now exclude inverse paths and the solution stopped relying on the fact Python 3.5+ has ordered mappings, this means it will now work if you use 3.4 or prior.